# UTF-8 in oracle 12C

Tags: sql, database, character-encoding, oracle12c

I have created some Oracle 12 dbs with the default encoding. They must be UTF-8 to support different languages.

How can I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the database character set, perform the following steps:

1. Shut down the database, using either a SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE or a
   SHUTDOWN NORMAL statement.
2. Do a full backup of the database because
   the ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET statement cannot be rolled back.

Complete the following statements:

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; -- or SHUTDOWN NORMAL; 
STARTUP;
```

Visit http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm for an alternate approach.

Comment: Don't use `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...`, it is not supported. Use the proper migration as described in the document.